# Optimizing sub-queries, making two queries become one

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

The following query is used to do a member search, in this example, only using the last name. The query returns in a few seconds if searching on a full matching name; but if `:LastName = 'S'`, then the query takes upwards of 12 seconds to return.

**How can I speed up this query? If I can do it in under a second with two queries, shouldn't I be able to make it just one query, just as fast?** Because of plugins and other methods, it would be easiest for me to have this be one query, hence my question.

The `Member` table holds every member we've ever had. The table has some members who we don't have any registration for, so they only exist in this table, not in `Registration` or `Registration_History`. `Registration_History` has extra information on most members that I want to display. `Registration` has most of the same information as RH (RH has some fields that Reg doesnt), but sometimes it has members that RH does not have, which is why it is joined here. **EDIT:** Members can have multiple rows in Registration. I want to fill the columns from Registration_History, however, some legacy members ONLY exist in Registration. Unlike other members,these legacy members only ever have 1 row in Registration, so I don't need to worry about how Registration is sorted, just that it only grabs 1 row from there.

[SQL Fiddle with sample database design](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2324f/2)

`MemberID` is indexed in all 3 tables. Before I put the `SELECT RHSubSelect.rehiId` subquery in, this query was taking almost a full minute to return.

If I split the query into 2 queries, doing this:

```
SELECT
    MemberID
FROM
    Member
WHERE 
    Member.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', :LastName, '%')
```

And then putting those `MemberID`s into an array and passing that array to `RHSubSelect.MemberID IN ($theArray)` (instead of the Member subquery), the results come back very quickly (about a second).

**Full query:** (Full SELECT statement is in the Fiddle, `SELECT *` for brevity)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
 Member
    LEFT JOIN
        Registration_History FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY)
            ON
                Registration_History.rehiId = (
                                                SELECT
                                                    RHSubSelect.rehiId
                                                FROM
                                                    Registration_History AS RHSubSelect
                                                WHERE
                                                    RHSubSelect.MemberID IN (
                                                                                SELECT
                                                                                    Member.MemberID
                                                                                FROM
                                                                                    Member
                                                                                WHERE 
                                                                                    Member.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', :LastName, '%')
                                                                            )                                                                   
                                                ORDER BY 
                                                    RHSubSelect.EffectiveDate DESC
                                                LIMIT 0, 1
                                            )                                   
    LEFT JOIN
        Registration FORCE INDEX(MemberID)
            ON
                Registration.MemberID = Member.MemberID
WHERE 
    Member.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', :LastName, '%') 
GROUP BY
    Member.MemberID
ORDER BY 
    Relevance ASC,LastName ASC,FirstName asc 
LIMIT 0, 1000
```

**MySQL Explain, with the `FORCE INDEX()` in the query:**
[image: "Mysql Explain"]

(If the image with the explain doesn't show, it's also here: http://oi41.tinypic.com/2iw4t8l.jpg)

Comment: The question is incomplete ... the part after "...FORCE_INDEX()..." is missing.

Comment: @DaDaDom After the "MySQL Explain, with the FORCE INDEX() in the query:" line? There should be a picture showing the EXPLAIN. I uploaded it via SO, but here is a tinypic of it: http://i41.tinypic.com/2iw4t8l.png

Comment: Ah, sorry, the images are blocked here at the company's proxy ...

Comment: Have you tried adding an index on Member.Lastname?

Comment: @DaDaDom An index on `Member.LastName` already exists

Comment: Index on LastName will be useless due to the leading wildcard

Comment: The query you showed us is incomplete (ORDER BY Relevance --> mysql reports an error: Unknow column 'Relevance'), and your SQLFiddle demo contains only the schema without any query. Please show the original query you want to optimize.

Comment: If you have multiple registration_history records for a member, which RegYear and which RegNumber do you want to use? Same for multiple registration records and the year / regnumber fields from that table.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you seem to be checking is the last name with a leading % in the like. This renders the index on that column useless, and your SQL is searching for it twice.

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do. Your SQL appears to get all the members who match on name to the one required, then get the last registration_history record for those. The one you get could be from any one of the matching members, which seems strange unless you only ever expect to get a single member.

If this is the case the following minor tidy (removing and IN and changing it to a JOIN) up will possibly slightly improve things.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(NULLIF(Registration_History.RegYear, ''), NULLIF(Registration.Year, '')) AS RegYear,
    COALESCE(NULLIF(Registration_History.RegNumber, ''), NULLIF(Registration.RegNumber, ''), NULLIF(Member.MemberID, '')) AS RegNumber,
    Member.MemberID,
    Member.LastName,
    Member.FirstName,
    CASE
        WHEN Member.LastNameTrimmed = :LastName
        THEN 1
        WHEN Member.LastNameTrimmed LIKE CONCAT(:LastName, '%')
        THEN 2
        ELSE 3
    END AS Relevance 
    FROM Member
    LEFT JOIN Registration_History FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY)
    ON Registration_History.rehiId = 
    (
        SELECT RHSubSelect.rehiId
        FROM Registration_History AS RHSubSelect
        INNER JOIN Member 
        ON RHSubSelect.MemberID = Member.MemberID
        WHERE Member.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', :LastName, '%')
        ORDER BY RHSubSelect.EffectiveDate DESC
        LIMIT 0, 1
    )                                   
    LEFT JOIN Registration FORCE INDEX(MemberID)
    ON  Registration.MemberID = Member.MemberID
    WHERE Member.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', :LastName, '%') 
    GROUP BY Member.MemberID
    ORDER BY Relevance ASC,LastName ASC,FirstName asc 
    LIMIT 0, 1000
```

However if this is not quite what you want then further changes might be possible.

Bit more of a clean up, eliminating one of the LIKEs with a leading wildcard:-

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(NULLIF(Sub2.RegYear, ''), NULLIF(Registration.Year, '')) AS RegYear,
    COALESCE(NULLIF(Sub2.RegNumber, ''), NULLIF(Registration.RegNumber, ''), NULLIF(Member.MemberID, '')) AS RegNumber,
    Member.MemberID,
    Member.LastName,
    Member.FirstName,
    CASE
        WHEN Member.LastNameTrimmed = :LastName
        THEN 1
        WHEN Member.LastNameTrimmed LIKE CONCAT(:LastName, '%')
        THEN 2
        ELSE 3
    END AS Relevance 
FROM Member
LEFT OUTER JOIN Registration 
ON  Registration.MemberID = Member.MemberID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT Registration_History.MemberID, Registration_History.rehiID, Registration_History.RegYear, Registration_History.RegNumber
    FROM Registration_History
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT RHSubSelect.MemberID, MAX(RHSubSelect.EffectiveDate) AS EffectiveDate
        FROM Registration_History AS RHSubSelect
        GROUP BY RHSubSelect.MemberID
    ) Sub1
    ON Registration_History.MemberID = Sub1.MemberID AND Registration_History.EffectiveDate = Sub1.EffectiveDate
) Sub2
ON  Sub2.MemberID = Member.MemberID
WHERE Member.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', :LastName, '%') 
GROUP BY Member.MemberID
ORDER BY Relevance ASC,LastName ASC,FirstName asc 
LIMIT 0, 1000
```

This is getting all the members with a matching name, their matching registration record and their registration_history record with the latest EffectiveDate.

I do not think the last GROUP BY is necessary (assuming that there is a 1 to 1 relationship between Members and Registration, and if not you probably want to use something other than GROUP BY), but I have left it in for now.

Afraid without table declares and some same data I can't really test it.

EDIT - Bit of a play, trying to reduce the quantities it is dealing with earlier in the select:-

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(NULLIF(Registration_History.RegYear, ''), NULLIF(Sub1.Year, '')) AS RegYear,
    COALESCE(NULLIF(Registration_History.RegNumber, ''), NULLIF(Sub1.RegNumber, ''), NULLIF(Sub1.MemberID, '')) AS RegNumber,
    Sub1.MemberID,
    Sub1.LastName,
    Sub1.FirstName,
    CASE
        WHEN Sub1.LastName = :LastName
        THEN 1
        WHEN Sub1.LastName LIKE CONCAT(:LastName, '%')
        THEN 2
        ELSE 3
    END AS Relevance 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        Member.MemberID,
        Member.LastName,
        Member.FirstName,
        Registration.Year,
        Registration.RegNumber,
        MAX(Registration_History.EffectiveDate) AS EffectiveDate
    FROM Member
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Registration 
    ON  Registration.MemberID = Member.MemberID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Registration_History 
    ON Registration_History.MemberID = Member.MemberID
    WHERE Member.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', :LastName, '%') 
    GROUP BY Member.MemberID,
        Member.LastName,
        Member.FirstName,
        Registration.Year,
        Registration.RegNumber
) Sub1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Registration_History
ON Registration_History.MemberID = Sub1.MemberID AND Registration_History.EffectiveDate = Sub1.EffectiveDate
ORDER BY Relevance ASC,LastName ASC,FirstName asc 
LIMIT 0, 1000
```

EDIT again.

Give this a try. The items you are sorting on are all from the members table so possibly makes sense to exclude the as early as possible in a subselect.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(NULLIF(Registration_History2.EffectiveDate, ''), NULLIF(Registration2.Year, '')) AS RegYear,
    COALESCE(NULLIF(Registration_History2.RegNumber, ''), NULLIF(Registration2.RegNumber, ''), NULLIF(Member.MemberID, '')) AS RegNumber,
    Member.MemberID,
    Member.LastName,
    Member.FirstName,
    Member.Relevance 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Member.MemberID,
                Member.LastName,
                Member.FirstName,
                CASE
                    WHEN Member.LastName = :LastName
                    THEN 1
                    WHEN Member.LastName LIKE CONCAT(:LastName, '%')
                    THEN 2
                    ELSE 3
                END AS Relevance 
        FROM Member
        WHERE Member.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', :LastName, '%')
        ORDER BY Relevance ASC,LastName ASC,FirstName asc 
        LIMIT 0, 1000
    ) Member
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT MemberID, MAX(EffectiveDate) AS EffectiveDate
        FROM Registration_History 
        GROUP BY MemberID
    ) Registration_History
    ON Registration_History.MemberID = Member.MemberID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Registration_History Registration_History2
    ON Registration_History2.MemberID = Registration_History.MemberID
    AND Registration_History2.EffectiveDate = Registration_History.EffectiveDate
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT MemberID, MAX(Year) AS Year
        FROM Registration 
        GROUP BY MemberID
    ) Registration
    ON Registration.MemberID = Member.MemberID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT MemberID, Year, MAX(RegNumber) AS RegNumber
        FROM Registration 
        GROUP BY MemberID, Year
    ) Registration2
    ON Registration2.MemberID = Member.MemberID
    AND Registration2.Year = Registration.Year
```

EDIT again

Not tested the following so this is more for just an idea of another way to try to get around the issue, using a little trick with GROUP_CONCAT:-

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(NULLIF(Registration_History.EffectiveDate, ''), NULLIF(Registration.Year, '')) AS RegYear,
    COALESCE(NULLIF(Registration_History.RegNumber, ''), NULLIF(Registration.RegNumber, ''), NULLIF(Member.MemberID, '')) AS RegNumber,
    Member.MemberID,
    Member.LastName,
    Member.FirstName,
    Member.Relevance 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Member.MemberID,
                Member.LastName,
                Member.FirstName,
                CASE
                    WHEN Member.LastName = :LastName
                    THEN 1
                    WHEN Member.LastName LIKE CONCAT(:LastName, '%')
                    THEN 2
                    ELSE 3
                END AS Relevance 
        FROM Member
        WHERE Member.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', :LastName, '%')
        ORDER BY Relevance ASC,LastName ASC,FirstName asc 
        LIMIT 0, 1000
    ) Member
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT MemberID, 
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(EffectiveDate ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC), ",", 1) AS EffectiveDate,
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(RegNumber ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC), ",", 1) AS RegNumber
        FROM Registration_History 
        GROUP BY MemberID
    ) Registration_History
    ON Registration_History.MemberID = Member.MemberID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT MemberID, 
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Year ORDER BY Year DESC), ",", 1) AS Year,
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(RegNumber ORDER BY Year DESC), ",", 1) AS RegNumber
        FROM Registration 
        GROUP BY MemberID
    ) Registration
    ON Registration.MemberID = Member.MemberID
```

Comment: Updated my question with the table explanation: The `Member` table holds every member we've ever had. The table has some members who we don't have any registration for, so they only exist in this table, not in `Registration` or `Registration_History`. `Registration_History` has extra information on most members that I want to display. `Registration` has most of the same information as RH (RH has some fields that Reg doesnt), but sometimes it has members that RH does not have, which is why it is joined here.

Comment: Does that explanation help?

Comment: It does, thank you. I think you do have a logical error in your SQL when more than one person matches :LastName as you will only use the most recent record for any of those people rather than the one that matches the memberid. Give my 2nd suggestion a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, that 2nd suggestion never came back; after two minutes I just killed it. Thanks though! It's very frustrating that it works beautifully as 2 queries, but I just can't get it into 1.

Comment: Can you post the table declares and a few sample records (or knock up an SQL fiddle)? If so I can test the query and see if I can improve it. Might also need some indexes playing with.

Comment: I'll see what I can put together for you, will be later today though. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers. Will look then. Possibly an index covering both MemberID and EffectiveDate might help the 2nd query

Comment: Here's an SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2324f/2 You obviously won't be able to recreate the speed problems though: my `Member` table has 194k rows, `Registration` has ~600k, and `Registration_History` has ~300k rows.

Comment: Cheers. Had a bit more of a play. Moved things round which will hopefully reduce the quantities being joined a bit earlier on. However a bit unsure about registration having ~3 times as many records as the Member table

Comment: No cigar - 86 seconds. The way our application works, Registration is supposed to have more than the Member table.

Comment: Are there multiple registration records per member? If so how do you define which one to use? Don't think you can speed this up much more.

Comment: Normally I would accept that a short search like 'S' is of course going to take long - but it bothers me that if I split it into two queries, getting the MemberIDs in one query and then getting the info for those MemberIDs in a 2nd query, it runs in under a second. If that's possible, doesn't that mean that I should be able to replicate those speeds in one query?

Comment: I would agree, but I am not sure how a search on a like against ~200k records is going to happen within a second if the last query above is taking 86 seconds on the same table

Comment: Another play. Knocking up a silly amount of test data for members this does appear reasonable in performance. But the efficiency of the sub selects against Registration and Registration_History will be heavily influenced by the indexes on them

Comment: Running all answers through `mysqlslap`. First run at your edited version ran at around 55secs again; so I modified it to http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0MLXD8dY and I get Benchmark Average number of seconds to run all queries: 1.255 seconds. Minimum number of seconds to run all queries: 1.226 seconds. Maximum number of seconds to run all queries: 1.299 seconds

Comment: Don't think your edited version will give you the results want. Your first sub query is only going to get a single max effective date (for any member) for an indeterminate member id, while the 2nd gets the max reg date (for any member) and an indeterminate memberid and year.

Comment: Have you put an index on MemberID and Year on registration, along with an index on MemberId and EffectiveDate on registration_history?

Comment: Ah, yea, I guess I would've realized it wasn't returning what I want if I hadn't minimized the SELECT so much. There is an index on `MemberID`, `RegYear`, and `EffectiveDate` individually, and also a combined index on `MemberID and EffectiveDate`. No combined index on MemberID and RegYear

Comment: Just copied and pasted your most recent edit query and ran it exactly as it's written: 515 seconds. This is without a combined index on MemberID and RegYear.

Comment: Try it with the combined indexes

Comment: 58 seconds with the combined index and a `FORCE INDEX` clause

Comment: Another attempt above.

Comment: Thanks for all the attempts! Your latest attempt I killed off at 300 seconds. I'm going to give @JamesHolderness the bounty, but thank you for all of your attempts!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Member
LEFT JOIN Registration USING (MemberID)
LEFT JOIN Registration_History ON rehiID = (
  SELECT rehiID
  FROM Registration_History AS RHSubSelect
  WHERE RHSubSelect.MemberID = Member.MemberID
  ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
WHERE Member.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', :LastName, '%')
```

The way it works, is you start by selecting from the *Member* table matching against the *LastName*. You then have simple `LEFT JOIN` to the *Registration* table, since a particular member can have at most 1 entry in that table. Finally you `LEFT JOIN` the *Registration_History* table with a subselect.

The subselect looks for the most recent *EffectiveDate* matching the current *MemberID* and returns the *rehiID* for that record. The `LEFT JOIN` must then match that *rehiID* exacty. If there are no entries in the *Registration_History* for that member, then nothing is joined.

In theory this should be relatively fast, since you are only performing the `LIKE` comparison in the main query. The *Registration* join should be fast since the table is indexed on *MemberID*. However, I suspect you'll need an additional index on the *Registration_History* to get the best performance.

You've already got the primary key, *rehID*, indexed which is what we need for the `LEFT JOIN` on *rehID*. However, the subquery needs to match the *MemberID* in the `WHERE` clause as well as sorting by the *EffectiveDate*. For the best performance there, I think you'll need an additional index combining the *MemberID* and *EffectiveDate* columns.

Note that my example query is just the bare minimum to keep things simple. You'll obviously need to replace the `*` with all the fields you want returned (the same as your original query). Also you'll need to add your `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses. However, the `GROUP BY` should not be required.

SQL Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a947a/1

The above fiddle show the full query except it has the last name hardcoded. I've modified your original sample data to include a couple more records and changed some of the values. I also added the extra index on the *Registration_History* table.

**Optimising for the LIMIT**

If you're going to doing timing runs again, I'd be curious to see how my query performs when using the modification suggested by **Kickstart** to do a subselect against the *Member* table first, before joining the *Registration* and *Registration_History* tables.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(NULLIF(Registration_History.RegYear, ''), NULLIF(Registration.Year, '')) AS RegYear,
    COALESCE(NULLIF(Registration_History.RegNumber, ''), NULLIF(Registration.RegNumber, ''), NULLIF(Member.MemberID, '')) AS RegNumber,
    Member.MemberID,
    Member.LastName,
    Member.FirstName,
    Member.Relevance
FROM (
  SELECT MemberID, LastName, FirstName,
    CASE
      WHEN Member.LastNameTrimmed = :LastName THEN 1
      WHEN Member.LastNameTrimmed LIKE CONCAT(:LastName, '%') THEN 2
      ELSE 3
    END AS Relevance 
  FROM Member
  WHERE Member.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', :LastName, '%')
  ORDER BY Relevance ASC,LastName ASC,FirstName ASC
  LIMIT 0, 1000
) Member
LEFT JOIN Registration USING (MemberID)
LEFT JOIN Registration_History ON rehiID = (
  SELECT rehiID
  FROM Registration_History AS RHSubSelect
  WHERE RHSubSelect.MemberID = Member.MemberID
  ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
```

When using a LIMIT, this should perform significantly better than my original query, since it won't have to carry out a bunch of unnecessary joins for the records that are excluded by the LIMIT.

Comment: Whoops - forgot to mention this in my original question. This was the original query I had written, and should've used in my question; it takes ~7 seconds, which is, again, ~6 seconds longer than splitting into 2 queries. Because the "2 query" method is very similar but so much faster, I assumed this was because the `LIMIT` isn't being applied to the `RHSubSelect`, so it is grabbing all the `MemberID`s that match from `Member` instead of only 1000. Splitting into 2 queries ensured that only 1000 were being used.

Comment: Whoops, no, I'll add that now. Will take some time.

Comment: Wow, that did it. I had to do an Index of type INDEX, not UNIQUE, due to some data issues, but I may be able to correct those and make it unique in the future. It runs at least under 1.5 seconds, which is probably the best I can hope for here. Now, the regular left join on `Registration` was selecting a member multiple times, so I did a sub select on that too with very minimal running time change.

Comment: If I add the `GROUP BY`, it changes the run time from ~1.5 seconds to 55 seconds. Do you have an explanation, or can point me in the right direction, on why `GROUP BY` would modify the running time so drastically?

Comment: @John Try looking at the `EXPLAIN` output for the query with and without the `GROUP BY` - that might suggest some reasons for the slow down. My initial thought would be that the `GROUP BY` forces it to sort the results by *MemberID* which it wouldn't otherwise have had to do. If the result set is big enough that could have a significant performance impact. Btw, I'm assuming you don't actually need the `GROUP BY` once you've got both joins working correctly?

Comment: Correct, at least with the test searches I ran, I don't need the `GROUP BY` once I've got both joins working correctly.

Comment: Running each answer through `mysqlslap`. Ran your answer with an  added subselect on `Registration` to keep each member to 1 row, and added an ORDER BY and LIMIT as well. Benchmark Average number of seconds to run all queries: 2.794 seconds. Minimum number of seconds to run all queries: 2.210 seconds. Maximum number of seconds to run all queries: 3.834 seconds

Comment: I can't see how this query will work as it is doing a JOIN from members against a correlated sub query.

Comment: @Kickstart You can't JOIN a correlated subquery as a table (as far as I know), but you can use a correlated subquery in the ON clause of a JOIN. Quoting from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html): "Subqueries in the FROM clause cannot be correlated subqueries, unless used within the ON clause of a JOIN operation."

Comment: @JamesHolderness - Interesting, although the performance downsides are a bit worrying. In effect it is doing the correlated sub query in the WHERE clause (which would be obvious using older style JOIN syntax), but does mean it is possibly performing many thousands of sub queries.

Comment: As an aside, testing your query against some test data I knocked up it takes about .66 seconds. My query takes about 0.4 seconds. Modifying yours to do a sub select against members (ie, like my query), sorting out the 1000 required records first reduces the time down to about 0.4.

Comment: @Kickstart Yes, it does mean it is performing thousands of subqueries, but since they are scalar queries with an appropriate index they should be really fast. As for doing the sub select against members first, that makes perfect sense when optimising for the LIMIT. I never considered that.

Comment: Your second query runs slightly faster, but as its written, it returns multiple rows per person (because of `Registration`): Benchmark Average number of seconds to run all queries: 1.995 seconds. Minimum number of seconds to run all queries: 1.905 seconds. Maximum number of seconds to run all queries: 2.349 seconds. I'm going to give you the bounty, yours simply are the fastest, but I'm not sure I can mark it as the answer yet. Thanks for being so willing to work with this!

Comment: @John Thanks for the bounty. I enjoyed working on this question. It has been interesting to see how other people approached the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly (you just need to select particular users and their latest history record - is that correct)? If yes, your problem is actually very easy variant of [greatest record per group problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group). No need for any subqueries:

#### Query #1

```
SELECT Member.*, rh1.*
FROM Member
LEFT JOIN Registration_History AS rh1 USING (MemberID)
LEFT JOIN Registration_History AS rh2
    ON rh1.MemberId = rh2.MemberId AND rh1.EffectiveDate < rh2.EffectiveDate
WHERE Member.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', :LastName, '%') 
    AND rh2.MemberId IS NULL
ORDER BY Relevance ASC,LastName ASC,FirstName ASC
LIMIT 0, 1000
```

#### Query #3

(#2 was removed, taking #3 here to avoid confusion in comments)

```
SELECT Member.*, max(rh1.EffectiveDate), rh1.*
FROM Member
LEFT JOIN Registration_History AS rh1 USING (MemberID)
WHERE Member.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', :LastName, '%') 
GROUP BY Member.MemberID
ORDER BY Relevance ASC,LastName ASC,FirstName ASC
LIMIT 0, 1000
```

#### Query #4

This one was inspired by James query, but removing the `limit` and `order by` (note that you should have defined index on EffectiveDate for not only this, but all queries to be efficient!)

```
select *
from Member
left join Registration_History AS rh1 on rh1.MemberID = Member.MemberID
    and rh1.EffectiveDate = (select max(rh2.EffectiveDate)
                             from Registration_History as rh2
                             where rh2.MemberID = Member.MemberID)
                        )
WHERE Member.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', :LastName, '%') 
ORDER BY Relevance ASC,LastName ASC,FirstName ASC
LIMIT 0, 1000
```

Please post the actual durations in your db!

Comment: Thanks for the response! Query #1 runs in about 0.6 seconds, but returns repeat Member rows, possibly because Registration can contain multiple rows for one member. How would I fix that without doing a subquery or skipping over results when I loop through them? Query #2 runs in ~6.5 seconds, but returns 0 rows when using the `set @prev_member` line. MySQL adds `# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).` to that line after I run the query. Without that line, the query returns in ~4 seconds, but has repeat rows for each member.

Comment: Dear @John, well, if the `Registration` table contains more rows for one member, then yes. But what do you actually want here? 1) Do you want to see fields of `Registration` table, but which registration for given member? In your query you use `group by` and `*` in select, which will produce undefined results for `Registration.*` fields. 2) Do you only want to filter those members, for which some `Registration` exists (i.e. not being interested in `Registration.*` fields themselves).

Comment: 1) I want to fill the columns from `Registration_History`, however, some legacy members ONLY exist in `Registration`. Unlike other members,these legacy members only ever have 1 row in `Registration`, so I don't need to worry about how `Registration` is sorted, just that it only grabs 1 row from there. After looking at the query more, I've realized that the `GROUP BY` wasn't doing what I thought it was. The `SELECT *` is just there for brevity; as I mentioned, the actual SELECT statement is in the SQL fiddle.

Comment: 2) Take a look at the SQL fiddle - I grab my info from RegHist, grabbing the record for that member with the latest effective date, but if it doesn't exist, then grab it from Reg. I don't think doing a subquery for Reg is going to slow it down at all, it's the RegHist that has been the culprit, I'll try it later this morning. What might seem to be my issue with getting Query #2 to run? I'm inexperienced in using MySQL variables.

Comment: Dear @John, [your SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2324f/2) is doesn't load properly. *"some legacy members ONLY exist in Registration"* -- so they do not exist in `Members` table? So the only table that contains all members is `Registration`, but they can be duplicated?

Comment: Er, said that wrong. ALL members exist in `Members`. ALL members exist in `Registration`. MOST members exist in `Registration_History`. For all intensive purposes, you can forget about Registration for now; eventually, that table will be removed. I don't mind doing a subquery in there for now. But what could my issue be with Query #2?

Comment: OK @John, I absolutely agree - let's remove `Registration` from the query now, to make it simple! Then it is easy - I just removed it from the queries above, so both queries should now show only 1 row per member! So the query #1 should definitely work and also try #2 - and please report the time elapsed also :-)

Comment: Query #1 is still running in under a second, yes with only 1 row. However, Query #2 is still running in 9 seconds and returning 0 rows.

Comment: Well, then I see no points in query #2. I have written it for you so that it runs faster than query #1. So go with query #1! Is it the speed you were looking for? How long did your original query run?

Comment: Yes, query #1 runs much quicker than my original query, however the answer by @James Holderness runs a tad bit faster than your query #1. They both seem to be equal efficiency, as both are runnning over `Registration_History` twice.

Comment: Dear @John, I will try to look at it over the weekend to see if it can be further optimized.

Comment: @John please try query #3. Please also post actual times of James' query (as a comment under his answer) and my query #1.

Comment: @John, I noticed James query doesn't do `order by` and `limit` as you requested. Try to remove it from my queries (or add to his query) for the elapsed times to be comparable.

Comment: Running all answers through `mysqlslap`. I added a left join on `Registration` to your queries to make them compatible with other answers. Query #1 is where I edited the most: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=fjXCWVrx . Query #1 Benchmark Average number of seconds to run all queries: 2.554 seconds. Minimum number of seconds to run all queries: 1.886 seconds. Maximum number of seconds to run all queries: 3.833 seconds.

Comment: Query #3 Benchmark Average number of seconds to run all queries: 13.797 seconds. Minimum number of seconds to run all queries: 13.797 seconds. Maximum number of seconds to run all queries: 13.797 seconds.

Comment: Query #4 Benchmark Average number of seconds to run all queries: 2.921 seconds. Minimum number of seconds to run all queries: 2.103 seconds. Maximum number of seconds to run all queries: 4.352 seconds.

Comment: @John In your pastebin of Query#1 you haven't included any fields from the registration or history tables in the SELECT. Surely that will make a significant difference to the performance?

Comment: @JamesHolderness For comparing one query vs the other, I minimized the SELECTs. NOW I realize I can't make sure I am getting the right row from the Reg and RegH tables...

Comment: @John, keep it simple - for the comparisons, I'd recommend not to use the `Registration` table - if it's this which makes things complicated. It is better not to test too much things at once. Especially when you are going to clean up the design later.

Comment: @John, how is James the fastest when my query runs at 2.554 and his query is 2.794? Returning multiple rows per person shouldn't count; that is of course faster because you save the time demanding `group by`.

Comment: @Tomas When I add the `rh1.RegYear` to the select statement, your query runs at 35 seconds, not 2.5 anymore. Thank you for all your work, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
set @lastname = 'Smith1';

-- explain extended
SELECT  
    COALESCE(NULLIF(Registration_History.RegYear, ''), NULLIF(Registration.Year, '')) AS RegYear,
    COALESCE(NULLIF(Registration_History.RegNumber, ''), NULLIF(Registration.RegNumber, ''), NULLIF(Member.MemberID, '')) AS RegNumber,
    Member.MemberID,
    Member.LastName,
    Member.FirstName,
    CASE
      WHEN Member.LastNameTrimmed = 'Smith' THEN 1
      WHEN Member.LastNameTrimmed LIKE CONCAT(@lastname, '%') THEN 2
      ELSE 3
    END AS Relevance 
FROM (
    SELECT  Member.*,
        ( SELECT RHSubSelect.rehiId
            FROM  Registration_History AS RHSubSelect
            WHERE RHSubSelect.MemberID = Member.MemberID                                         
            ORDER BY RHSubSelect.EffectiveDate DESC
            LIMIT 0,1
         ) rh_MemberId
    FROM Member
    WHERE Member.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', @lastname, '%')
) Member
LEFT JOIN  Registration_History 
    ON Registration_History.rehiId = Member.rh_MemberId
LEFT JOIN Registration -- FORCE INDEX(MemberID)
    ON Registration.MemberID = Member.MemberID
GROUP BY Member.MemberID
ORDER BY Relevance ASC,LastName ASC,FirstName asc 
LIMIT 0, 1000
;
```

Comment: Query took 16 seconds to run.  Honestly, I'm not sure how this is written any more efficient than the @James Holderness's  or Tomas's answer, you've just sort of re-written organized the way the sub selects are. Can you please provide an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's my shot and I used a variety of pieces.  One, I had to take the "relevance" field from one as you did not indicate how to make it work.  Next, since you wanted the latest entry from the registration history for a given member (if they existed in R/H), it appears that the effective date correlated with the ReHiID so I used that as it appears that would be a great key to work on for subsequent left-join.

So, the inner query makes the preliminary pass on just the criteria of the name you are looking for, applies relevance and limits the 1000 entries there.  This way it doesn't have to go through 20,000 entries at the outer level and join... just the 1000 that could qualify.

That result is then left-joined to the other tables as indicated... Registration of only a single entry (if exist) and left-joined to the R/H on the member AND the max ReHiID.

To apply the name you are looking for, just change the ( select @LookForMe := 'S' ) sqlvars line in the query...

```
select *
   from
      ( select
              M.*,
              max( RH.EffectiveDate ) as MaxEffectiveDate,
              max( R.RegNumber ) as MaxRegNumber,
              CASE WHEN M.LastNameTrimmed = @LookForMe THEN 1
              WHEN M.LastNameTrimmed LIKE CONCAT(@LookForMe, '%') THEN 2
              ELSE 3 END AS Relevance 
           from
              ( select @LookForMe := 'S' ) sqlvars,
              Member M
                 LEFT JOIN Registration_History RH
                    on M.MemberID = RH.MemberID
                 LEFT JOIN Registration R
                    on M.MemberID = R.MemberID
           where 
              M.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', 'S', '%')
           group by
              M.MemberID
           order by
              Relevance, 
              M.LastName,
              M.FirstName
           limit
              0,1000 ) PreQuery
      LEFT JOIN Registration R2
         on PreQuery.MemberNumber = R2.MemberNumber
         AND PreQuery.MaxRegNumber = R2.RegNumber
      LEFT JOIN Registration_History RH2
         ON PreQuery.MemberNumber = RH2.MemberNumber
        AND PreQuery.MaxEffectiveDate = RH2.EffectiveDate
```

Lets see how quick this runs with your production data and how close we get.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This consistently took 0.99 seconds. However, This returns multiple rows for each Member; probably because `Registration` can contain more than one row for each Member. I want just one row per member. However, like the other answers, I'm not really sure how this query is any more efficient than @James Holderness's response. Seems to be the same, if not less efficient.

Comment: @John, I added MAX() for the registration too and slightly altered LEFT-joins outside the prequery.  I'd like to consider the times of this revision, and if it is consistently faster (at just 1 second) even with the group by, then why would it not be a viable solution.

Comment: Well, at the moment it's returning multiple rows for each person. Also, the MAX() won't always select the correct row. It is possible that a `MAX(rehiId)` won't always have the latest `RH.EffectiveDate`, which is why the queries require the latest `RH.EffectiveDate`.

Comment: @John, Revised for max effective date and join on both qualifying fields since what should have been a unique ID causing duplicates to occur.

Comment: Slower now, at 3 seconds. What's the point of the outer query, when you are just selecting all the information in the inner query?

Comment: Running each answer through `mysqlslap`. Benchmark Average number of seconds to run all queries: 9.323 seconds. Minimum number of seconds to run all queries: 9.066 seconds. Maximum number of seconds to run all queries: 9.446 seconds.

Comment: @John, icckkkk on the time... How many records are there (roughly) that this time is going against... it may be that you need to compare over partition or via MySQL variables to determine the first entry and just keep the data on those lines only... but other instances of queries that are not considering the most recent per each possible file I don't think you would get without the prequalification.

Comment: My Member table has 194k rows, Registration has ~600k, and Registration_History has ~300k rows